# how would I get camera and mic presence in device with html5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webrtc, getusermedia

I am writing an app that uses camera and microphone with HMTL5, I read out all the documentation to use camera and mic with getUserMedia, webRTC, webAudio,etc.. APIs, but I cant figure out how before going with getusermedia or any other api, how can I know whether camera or microphone is connected or not?

I would like to implement my application flow based on the connection status of camera or microphone.

Is it possible to get devices connection status?

Comment: "Is it possible to get devices connection status" -  .Yes it is very usually for bugs in webrtc chat apps. When you allow access to mic , webcam on firefox(win) . Losing audio stream in webcam with mic or without mic . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586889/how-to-detect-microphone-type/31601758#31601758 this is nice start. You need to implement also some handler for specific browser/platform target (for chrome no need for this).Get list of devices before any other operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the [example 2](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html#examples), you can see there is an exception handling for camera not available.

Comment: It is error callback only when user denies the request it will call. before asking for permission how can i get connection status?

Comment: asking for permission when no camera is available, make no sense right?

Comment: I bet having no camera browser will not show any requests to the use and fail the call directly. That would be trivial to check.

Comment: @OlegMihailik try it out now in linux it will ask for permission to get access to camera without camera.

Comment: How would you recognize which error you got? either no camera found or permission denied?

Comment: Will you be able to make a quick JSBin script?