# How to detect microphone type

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia

I use webRTC (getUserMedia) for recording sound and uploading it to backend server. All works well except i am unable to determine the microphone type (is it a built-in mic, usb mic, headset mic, sth else?)

Does anybody know how can i detect the type?

Comment: what's your endgame? i doubt something like that exists in the WebRTC api.

Comment: I guess, you can do it in chrome using `MediaStreamTrack.getSources(callback)` , check [this](https://simpl.info/getusermedia/sources/) out.

Comment: @mido22 That's outdated. Please see [this](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output) instead. It's called `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` now and is available as a polyfill in [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) for browsers that don't have it yet.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) to list the user's cameras and microphones, and try to infer types from their labels (there's no mic-type field unfortunately).

The following code works in Firefox 39 and Chrome 45 *:

```js
var stream;
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio:true })
.then(s => (stream = s), e => console.log(e.message))
.then(() => navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices())
.then(devices => {
  stream && stream.stop();
  console.log(devices.length + " devices.");
  devices.forEach(d => console.log(d.kind + ": " + d.label));
})
.catch(e => console.log(e));

var console = { log: msg => div.innerHTML += msg + "<br>" };
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

In Firefox on my system, this produces:

```
5 devices.
videoinput: Logitech Camera
videoinput: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
audioinput: default (Logitech Camera)
audioinput: Built-in Microphone
audioinput: Logitech Camera
```

Now, there are some caveats: [By spec](http://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#methods-2) the labels only show if device access is granted, which is why the snippet asks for it (try it both ways).

Furthermore, Chrome 45 requires persistent permissions (a bug?) which is not available in insecure HTTP, so you may need to [reload this question in HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586889/how-to-detect-microphone-type/31601758#31601758) first to see labels. If you do that, don't forget to revoke access in the URL bar afterwards, or Chrome will persist it, which is probably a bad idea on stackoverflow!

Alternatively, try [https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/) which works in regular Chrome thanks to the [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) polyfill, but requires you to grant persistent permission and reload the page before you see labels (because of how it was written).

(*) **EDIT:** Apparently, enumerateDevices just got put back under an experimental flag in Chrome 45, so you need to enable it [as explained here](http://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output). Sorry about that. Shouldn't be long I hope.

Comment: Hmm, I'm having trouble running the snippet in Chrome 46 suddenly. Not sure what changed. [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsa6rrt7) works for me.